# What are "helpful flags" in the Deputy Badge?

Tags: support, flag-badges

I was wondering what are the "helpful flags" in the Deputy Badge. There doesn't seem to be a badge description when you click on the badge. I thought it was the number of times comments where upvoted as "helpful" but it is apparently not that since that my "helpful flag" score doesn't change in accordance to the "helpful" upvotes of my comments.

Comment: Answered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/what-does-the-helpful-flag-mean

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Any time you flag a comment or a post, it either enters a review queue for higher-reputation users to review, or it goes directly to a moderator to review.

If the reviewers approve of the flag, or if the moderator agrees with it, then it counts as "helpful".

Comment: Thank you, I found it really confusing!

Comment: Ahhh! Right! "Helpful flags" are _flags which were deemed helpful_.  I thought there was a thing where you could flag a post as "helpful", using a "helpful flag". I couldn't figure out why you'd need this, in a world with up-votes.

Comment: If any post deserves the helpful flag for being helpful, it is this one.